# Is there a OnRestart() event listener for a C# Windows service? How can I see if the Windows Service was Restarted?

Tags: c#, service

I have a C# Windows Service. I have the following events

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{    
    string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server running on " + url);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(LogMessage.Message);   
    SignalR.Dispose();
}
```

The problem is that I am doing a

`Environment.Exit(1);`

when my service code has completed running its operations, I have properties set on my service such that it restarts after 1 minute (when it receives a failure). It seems that when it fails it doesn't actually hit the "stop" event so my log never gets written. Is there a

`OnRestart()`

event or something like that? I'm trying to figure out how to get my log written out before I exit the service. It would usually write the log when I manually clicked "Stop Service" from the services dialog in Windows. But I am no longer manually clicking stop to end the service, I am automatically restarting it and forcing a error in the service so I don't have to manually stop and re-start it.

You would think I would just be able to do

```
eventLog1.WriteEntry("blah blah");
```

before I exit the code, but I can't because It's out of scope and I'm exiting the code in a seperate class :(

Comment: Using Environment.Exit() in a service is just fundamentally wrong.  It is the service manager that decides when you need to quit.  Implement once-a-minute operation with a Timer.

Comment: I'm not writing windows services anymore. I'm writing console apps and let ["TopShelf"](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html) run them as windows services. You can specify on start, on stop, on exception, and some other things as well - basic service only requires 10 rows of code.

Comment: @HansPassant Incorrect, your opinion is **not** fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you wrap a try/catch block around the section of code which is doing work? If it fails for whatever reason, it jumps in that catch block where you can raise the OnStop() event.

```
try
{            
    //Your service code
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    OnStop();
}
```

Comment: This *seems* like it would work. I will give it a try.